Does there exist a complete Lorentzian metric on $S^2$ with $n$ points removed, $n\geq 3$?
Let $n$ be an integer with $n\geq 3$, and let $X$ be a copy of $S^2$ with $n$ points removed (as a smooth 2D manifold). I am wondering about the following question:

Does there exist a complete Lorentzian metric on $X$?

We note the answer is already "yes" under any of the following changes to the above requirements:

if we drop the "complete" requirement. Then we can embed $X$ as a cylinder with $n-2$ points removed, in Minkowski space $\mathbb{R}^{1|2}$, such that the vertical axis of the cylinder is along the "time" axis; then the pullback of the standard Minkowski metric, to $X$, gives a Lorentzian metric on $X$, but it is not complete due to the $n-2$ "holes".
if we change "Lorentzian" to "Riemannian". Indeed, it is well-known that any smooth manifold (without boundary) admits a complete Riemannian metric.
if $n\in\{1,2\}$ instead of $n\geq3$. Indeed, in the case $n=2$, $X$ is the cylinder, which embeds in $\mathbb{R}^{1|2}$ with cylinder axis along the "time axis", and gets an induced complete Lorentzian metric by pullback; and for the case $n=1$, $X$ is diffeomorphic to just $\mathbb{R}^2$, which already admits a complete Lorentzian metric as the Minkowski space $\mathbb{R}^{1|1}$.

My guess is that the answer to the above question is "no", but I'm not sure how to approach proving this; would anyone have a hint or reference suggestion?
